# Postman pre-request to get token doesn't work

Tags: javascript, spring-security, postman, urlencode

At this time I can perform succesfully my Postman request to get my token. I'm using these parameters :

-Basic Authorization in the headers

-and this body
-[image]

Now I would like to get this request as a pre-request script (and use an environment variable for the token).

Here is the script :

```
pm.sendRequest({
    url: 'http://localhost:8084/oauth/token',
    method: 'POST',
    header: {
        'Authorization':'Basic Y2xpZW50OnBhc3N3b3Jk',
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    data:{
        'password':'secret',
        'username':'admin',
        'grant_type':'password'
    }
}, (err, res) => pm.environment.set("token", res.json().access_token));
```

It doesn't work with the response : `Full authentication is required to access this resource`.

What is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could change the `data` section to something like this?

```
body:{
   mode:"urlencoded",
   urlencoded:[
      {
         key:"grant_type",
         value:"password"
      },
      {
         key:"username",
         value:"admin"
      },
      {
         key:"password",
         value:"secret"
      }
   ]
}
```

A great resource for `pm.sendRequest()` examples can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/madebysid/b57985b0649d3407a7aa9de1bd327990)

Comment: Of course I can and I did and It works. Big thanks for that.